# jsreport 2.0 BeforeRender Not Working

Tags: handlebars.js, jsreport

I am working on jsreport v2.0 and wants to render the data for the report. I am using handlebars and phantom-pdf and my beforeRender function is not getting called by default. 
For jsreport v2.0, i have added the listener for the beforeRender as following but still it did not seem to be called by default to render the data.

```
function beforeRenderListeners1(req,res){
     console.log("Listener Called");
}

const jsreport = require('jsreport-core')({
})    

jsreport.beforeRenderListeners.add('beforeRenderListeners1', (req, res) => {
     console.log("hello");
     req.data.check = abc();
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since i don't know the complete code that you are using i will go ahead and provide you a snippet that works in latest jsreport-core v2 (2.0.3) with node 8

```
const jsreport = require('jsreport-core')()

jsreport.use(require('jsreport-handlebars')())

jsreport.beforeRenderListeners.add('beforeRenderListeners1', (req, res) => {
     console.log("before render called")
     req.data = req.data || {}
     req.data.check = 'check pass'
})

jsreport.init().then(() => {
  console.log('started')

  return jsreport.render({
    template: {
      content: '<p>sample demo content, check: {{check}}</p>',
      engine: 'handlebars',
      recipe: 'html'
    }
  })
}).then((res) => {
  console.log('render done')
  console.log(res.content.toString())
}).catch((err) => console.error(err))
```

put that in a file and then run it, you will see the message `before render called` being printed in console.

Comment: I added the code snippet you provided in handlebar script and have just {{check}} tag in html <p>. But i am still not able to obtain before render called in console. I am using latest jsreport-core v2 and node 8 as well

Comment: hmm it will be good to know the full code that you are trying or even better the project that you are using, maybe it is something setup in wrong way. if you can create a github repository with your code i can take a look